# What are Starlink's available momentum unloading strategies?

Tags: spacex, attitude-determination-and-control, starlink, gyroscope

Today's Teslarati article [SpaceX wants to offer Starlink internet to consumers after just six launches](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-teases-starlink-internet-service-debut/) talks about the new website https://www.starlink.com/ shows several images from it, and tries to describe some of the bits on the Starlink spaceraft itself.

[image]

Caption for [full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frGrS.jpg), shown is a cropped section.

> Starlink’s star trackers (left; used for precise pointing and positioning) and what are likely four gyros, also used for pointing and orientation. (SpaceX)

I don't think the satellites have cold gas thrusters, but there is one Hall effect ion thruster for orbital maneuvers (e.g. raising, lowering, phasing, station-keeping).

**Question:** What are the strategies that are available to the Starlink satellites for momentum-unloading of the control gyros?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [Elon](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1132906066423889920) via twitter, magnetic torquers.

> Magnetic torque rods for desaturation of momentum wheels.