# How much krypton do Starlink satellites carry when they are first deployed?

Tags: spacex, starlink, station-keeping, electric-propulsion, deorbit

Starlink satellites use krypton as propellant.

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36471/12102) roughly estimates 2.3 kg of Krypton based on a total delta-V of 190 m/s and an exhaust velocity of 20,000 m/s.

But how close is that to reality? Is it known how much propellant is loaded into a Starlink satellite at launch?

Comment: I think it would be helpful in tailoring the answers if you could explain what, *precisely* is unclear to you about the information provided by Google and Wikipedia, and what you did and didn't understand about the results of your research. That way, you prevent people wasting their time by repeating things you already know, or things that you already found and didn't understand.

Comment: I could only find another question which says it uses krypton

Comment: @JoeJobs then put that in your question and explain why this isn't a duplicate by describing what further information you need.

Comment: Most of an answer here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starlink#Satellite_revisions  though does not talk about how how much xenon.

Comment: I just edited the question, can you take a look please?

Comment: There are links from comments in this question https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36455/delta-v-of-starlink-satellites?noredirect=1&lq=1 which look speculative but that's probably all there is to go on unless someone can find a paper trail with more authority to it. You'll have to work through yourself though or you could raise a new question if you aren't sure how to do this.

Comment: Not sure what other question to ask. Btw how many thrusters these satellites have?

Comment: @JoeJobs not sure but poring over drawings at the bottom of https://www.starlink.com I think that I see only one per satellite. Those seems to show [four gyros](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36472/12102) which would presumably rotate the craft until the ion engine was pointed in the right direction before it was turned on. More about small Hall effect thrusters [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36200/12102).